# How do I link with FreePascal a NASM program calling a DLL?

Tags: dll, nasm, freepascal

## Problem

I have a function "bob" written in assembler (nasm), which makes use of functions in kernel32.dll. And I have a program in FreePascal, that calls "bob".

I use nasm with:

```
nasm -fwin32 bob.asm
```

In FreePascal I declare:

```
{$link bob.obj}

function bob(s:pchar):longint; stdcall; external name 'bob';
```

But I get an error when I compile with fpc, telling it doesn't find GetStdHandle and WriteConsoleA (without @n suffix), which are declared extern in bob.asm. I would like to tell fpc to look for them in kernel32.dll, or in an adequate import library.

However, when I use the same function in pure assembly program, it works fine with nasm and golink. And when I don't call DLL functions, I can link with FreePascal with no trouble.

How can I link kernel32 functions with FreePascal, so that assembly functions "see" them ?

---

## A Solution

Given by BeniBela. I change names so that things are easy to follow.

```
program dlltest;

function WindowsGetStdHandle(n: longint): longint; stdcall;
   external 'kernel32.dll' name 'GetStdHandle';

{$asmmode intel}
procedure WrapperGetStdHandle; assembler; public name 'AliasGetStdHandle';
asm
   jmp WindowsGetStdHandle
end;


{$link myget.obj}

function AsmGetStdHandle(n: longint): longint; stdcall;
   external name 'gethandle';

const STDOUT = -11;

begin
   writeln(AsmGetStdHandle(STDOUT));
   writeln(WindowsGetStdHandle(STDOUT));
end.
```

With this in assembly, in myget.asm:

```
section .text

extern AliasGetStdHandle

global gethandle

gethandle:
   mov   eax, [esp+4]
   push  eax
   call  AliasGetStdHandle
   ret   4
```

**WindowsGetStdHandle** is another name for GetStdHandle in kernel32.dll.

**WrapperGetStdHandle** only jump to the preceding, it's here for the *[alias](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu61.html)* or *[public name](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu71.html)* capability : we give it the name AliasGetStdHandle for external objects. This is the important part, the function get visible to the assembly program.

**AsmGetStdHandle** is the name in FreePascal of the assembly function *gethandle*. It calls WrapperStdHandle (nicknamed AliasGetStdHandle), which jumps to WindowsGetStdHandle, the DLL function.

And we are done, now the assembly program can be linked, without changing anything in it. All the renaming machinery is done in the pascal program calling it.

The only drawback: the need for a wrapper function, but it's not overpriced for a fine control of names.

---

## Another solution

If kernel32.dll is not specified in declaration of WindowsGetStdHandle, but with {$linklib kernel32}, then the symbol gets visible in object files linked in the pascal program. However, it seems the $linklib directive alone is not enough, one still has to declare in pascal some function refering to it

```
program dlltest;

{$linklib kernel32}

function WindowsGetStdHandle(n: longint): longint; stdcall;
   external name 'GetStdHandle';

{$link myget.obj}

function AsmGetStdHandle(n: longint): longint; stdcall;
   external name 'gethandle';

const STDOUT = -11;

begin
   writeln(AsmGetStdHandle(STDOUT));
   writeln(WindowsGetStdHandle(STDOUT));
end.
```

With the following assembly program. AliasGetStdHandle is replaced with GetStdHandle, which now points directly to kernel32 function.

```
section .text

extern GetStdHandle

global gethandle

gethandle:
         mov   eax, [esp+4]
         push  eax
         call  GetStdHandle
         ret   4
```

But this only works when using the external linker (gnu ld), with command

```
fpc -Xe dlltest.pas
```

When omitting opton '-Xe', fpc gives the following error

```
Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.0 [2011/12/25] for i386
Copyright (c) 1993-2011 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Win32 for i386
Compiling dlltest.pas
Linking dlltest.exe
dlltest.pas(17,1) Error: Asm: Duplicate label __imp_dir_kernel32.dll
dlltest.pas(17,1) Error: Asm: Duplicate label __imp_names_kernel32.dll
dlltest.pas(17,1) Error: Asm: Duplicate label __imp_fixup_kernel32.dll
dlltest.pas(17,1) Error: Asm: Duplicate label __imp_dll_kernel32.dll
dlltest.pas(17,1) Error: Asm: Duplicate label __imp_names_end_kernel32.dll
dlltest.pas(17,1) Error: Asm: Duplicate label __imp_fixup_end_kernel32.dll
dlltest.pas(17,1) Fatal: There were 6 errors compiling module, stopping
Fatal: Compilation aborted
```

Comment: @ edit: Because you removed the alias from my example. If you add ` alias: 'GetStdHandle'; it should work. (although I used _GetStdHandle@4 in pascal and assembly. you can also have both aliases to be sure)

Comment: Silly me! I didn't quite understand this 'alias' stuff, but now I see it's essential to your solution. I'll change this right now.

Comment: I amended my answer. Tried to comment on BeniBela's findings. But it seems to be related to import libs. Apparently the FPC linker only generates those stubs for FPC owned symbols.

Comment: @Marco Looks like you're right: when using $linklib alone, it doesn't work, but if I declare also a reference to GetStdHandle in Pascal, I can use the symbol in assembly. I wonder if it's possible to use directly Windows unit, but I can't get the right name (something like _WINDOWS$$_GetStdHandle I think, but I get strange errors where $$ is replaced with a PATH). See also http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu125.html for name mangling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how to fix the linking issue directly, but you could declare public wrapper functions that export these functions from the Pascal source.

E.g.:

```
{$ASMMODE INTEL}
procedure WrapperGetStdHandle; assembler; public; alias: '_GetStdHandle@4';
asm  jmp GetStdHandle end;
procedure WrapperWriteConsoleA; assembler; public; alias: '_WriteConsoleA@20';
asm  jmp WriteConsoleA end;
```

Comment: Now I got it right with the alias directive, which I didn't understand well. I'll wait some more time to see if someone comes up with solution not involving a wrapper, but this one is already very fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, according to FP documentation, 'alias' is deprecated and should be replaced by 'public name' (see the links in the question). This does not detract from the value of your answer.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of that (alias deprecation, so don't hold it against BeniBela;-)

Comment: Btw: shouldn't those be stdcall?

Comment: Doesn't really matter if stdcall or not, since the functions have no stack frame

Comment: @Beni. It matters because with stdcall, arguments must be passed on stack. However, with optimizations (-O2 at least) and default (register) calling convention, first arguments are not passed on stack. See http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu80.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: yeah, but that's not important, since the *wrapper* does not take any arguments anyways. And the assembler source just pushes them without knowning about the declared function signature

Comment: Damned, you're right ! :-) I completely forgot it's a procedure with no arg, since it justs wait for assembly code to do all the job.

Comment: I give you the bounty, your solution is still the best (compilation with $linklib and -Xe is awkward, and it needs external linker). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is some import library automatically linked by nasm them for use with nasm code, and probably you need to link the relevant stubs from that library too.

**amended:**

It might be a problem with smart linking. As said FPC generates import stubs on the fly, but only when needed. Because the Windows unit (that holds all core WINAPI calls) is so large, smart linking (only adding what you use) is activated for it. (there are other reasons too)

The NASM originated obj is outside FPC's control, so the relevant functions are not generated for it.

If that is the case, BeniBela's code might work because it forces a reference from FPC code, linking in the symbols. This is speculation though, it might be something with the decoration too, or something with the leading underscore.

Testing that is simple, use the functions from pascal code without the declarations from Benibela.

Btw, FPC's default is NOT stdcall, so BenBela's functions should probably get a stdcall modifier

Comment: Nasm is not a linker. Golink, the linker I use with nasm, can read DLL files directly, without import library (command is just: golink /console bob.obj kernel32.dll). So, the problem I have, is showing freepascal that my linked object file has external dependencies to a dll (which golink sees automatically), and to resolve these dependencies.

Comment: That's my point. FPC's internal linker also can do this, but probably only does so for its native code, not external .objs.

Comment: I tried that before, it does not work, unless the functions are exported again with public. Also putting public on the imported functions itself, did not work.

Comment: I didn't find a way to specify *something* to the linker to force linking of object file with a given library. Not very clear for me wether it needs an import lib or if it could use ld directly with a dll, anyway, it does not seem to work (maybe I missed a decisive command line option or something else).